# Crossed for loops: Pick i th element of first loop then loop completely through second loop

Tags: r, for-loop

Suppose I have the following code:

```
    X    <- model.matrix(~factor(1:2))
    beta <- c(1, 2)
```

I then draw 70 and 40 values from two multivariate normal distributions:

```
    library(MASS)
    S1 <- mvrnorm(70, mu = c(0,0), Sigma = matrix(c(10, 3, 3, 2), ncol = 2))
    S2 <- mvrnorm(40, mu = c(0,0), Sigma = matrix(c(10, 4, 4, 2), ncol = 2))
```

As can be easily seen `S1` is `70x2` matrix und `S2` a `40x2` matrix.

Now I build a for loop in `R`:

```
    z <- list()
    for(i in 1:dim(S2)[1]){
        z[[i]] <- X %*% beta + X %*% S1[1,] + X %*% S2[i,] + rnorm(2, mean = 0, sd = 0.45)
    Y <- do.call(rbind, z)
    }
```

This gives me a matrix that contains all combinations for the `40` elements in `S2` with the `1`st element of `S1`. What I want is to completely cross the two matrices `S1` and `S2`. That is I want the for loop to pick out `S1[1,]` first, then iterate completely through `S2[i,]` (e.g. in an inner loop) and store the results in a matrix then pick out `S1[2,]` iterate again through `S2[i,]` and store the results in a matrix and so on. If I would need to give a name to what I am looking for I would say `"crossed for loops"`. I find it incredibly hard to come up with `R`-code that will allow me to do this. Any hints would be appreciated.

---

Maybe the idea will get clearer with this example:

My idea is equivalent to construction 70 `for`-loops for every element in `S1[i,]` and binding the result in a `70*40*2x1` matrix:

```
    for(i in 1:dim(S2)[1]){
    z[[i]] <- X %*% beta+X %*% S1[1,]+X %*% S2[i,]+rnorm(2, mean = 0 , sd = sigma)
    Y1 <- unname(do.call(rbind, z))
    }

    for(i in 1:dim(S2)[1]){
    z[[i]] <- X %*% beta+X %*% S1[2,]+X %*% S2[i,]+rnorm(2, mean = 0 , sd = sigma)
    Y2 <- unname(do.call(rbind, z))
    }

    for(i in 1:dim(S2)[1]){
    z[[i]] <- X %*% beta+X %*% S1[3,]+X %*% S2[i,]+rnorm(2, mean = 0 , sd = sigma)
    Y3 <- unname(do.call(rbind, z))
    }

    .
    .
    .

    for(i in 1:dim(S2)[1]){
    z[[i]] <- X %*% beta+X %*% S1[70,]+X %*% S2[i,]+rnorm(2, mean = 0 , sd = sigma)
    Y70 <- unname(do.call(rbind, z))
    }

    Y <- rbind(Y1, Y2, Y3, …, Y70)
```

What I ideally would want is to do this with `for`-loops or any other flexible way that can handle different dimensions for `S1` and `S2`.

Comment: Your example isn't [complete or reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so it is difficult to precisely answer. It seems like you could probably use `outer` here but it is unclear what you expect the result to be (given you code isn't runnable).

Comment: Sorry about that. The example should be reproducible now.

Comment: Yes, I thought I mentioned this in the text: "store the results in a matrix". But I may have been unclear.

Ideally the output would be a matrix. I thought about concatenating the matrices for every `S1[i,], i = 1, …, 70` after every iteration through `S2[j,]` to form one big matrix.

Comment: It should be a `(70*40*2)x2 = 5600x2`-matrix: `70 := number of elements in S1`, `40 := number of elements in S2`, `2 := number of rows in X`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about me being so slow, the semifinals start tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that this was not a problem with `for`-loops but with the way I stored the variables. The solution to what I want is:

```
library(MASS)
z <- list()
y <- list()
for(j in 1:dim(S1)[1]){
    for(i in 1:dim(S2)[1]){
        z[[i]] <- X %*% beta+X %*% S1[j,]+X %*% S2[i,]+matrix(rnorm(2, mean = 0 , sd = sigma), ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
        Z <- unname(do.call(rbind, z))
    }
        y[[j]] <- Z
        Y <- unname(do.call(rbind, y))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

OK. I might do a few things to make this as efficient as possible. First, we can pre-calculate all the matrix multiplication with

```
Xb <- X %*% beta
XS1 <- X %*% t(S1)
XS2 <- X %*% t(S2)
```

Then we can clculate all the combinations of the S1/S2 values with `expand.grid`

```
idx <- unname(c(expand.grid(A=1:ncol(XS1), B=1:ncol(XS2))))
```

Then we can define the transformation

```
fx<-function(a, b) {
    t(Xb + XS1[,a, drop=F] + XS2[,b,drop=F] + rnorm(2, mean = 0, sd = 0.45))
}
```

we assume we will be passed an index for S1 and an index for S2. Then we combine the data as in your formula. Finally, we use this helper function and the indexes with a set of `do.call`s

```
xx <- do.call(rbind, do.call(Map,c(list(fx), idx)))
```

First we use `Map` to calculate all the combinations, then we use `rbind` to merge all the results. This actually produces a 2800x2 matrix. (70*40)*2. The rows are ordered with S1 moving the fastest, then S2.